# Anchor initialize account with PDA as payer

Tags: anchor, solana-program

Is it possible to use a PDA as the payer in an anchor init macro. If so how?
I have tried simply setting the payer to be a PDA but have received the error.

"signer privilege escalated"

```
    #[account(mut, seeds = [some_seeds], bump)]
    payer: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(init, payer = payer, space = some_space, owner = some_owner)]
    inited_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is possible for a PDA to pay for initializing an account. The trick is that a PDA needs to be owned by the system program but signed for by the program the PDA is derived from. Note that I've added the `signer` constraint, modified the account type to `SystemAccount`. You'll also need a `seeds::program` constraint if the program signing is different from the program executing this instruction.

```
    #[account(
      signer,
      mut, 
      seeds = [some_seeds], 
      bump, 
      seeds::program = [program_account]
    )]
    payer: SystemAccount<'info>,
    #[account(init, payer = payer, space = some_space, owner = some_owner)]
    inited_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
```

You also don't necessarily have to check the seeds here, unless required for security reasons.

```
    #[account(mut)]
    payer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(init, payer = payer, space = some_space, owner = some_owner)]
    inited_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
```

Comment: How are you signing the create account tx via the pda in the second snippet.
without passing in the seeds and bump to be used for invoke_signed ix ? also wdnt Signer type fail as a client will pass the pda signed field as false ? only when the program does a ix can it sign for the pda. unless my understanding of the signer type is incomplete.

Comment: - Signatures come from outside the transaction itself. How to sign a transaction with a PDA is a separate question. This is an example of a function that can the question asker intends to call via CPI.
- No, when constructing the CPI transaction, the program handles assigning the meta account information
- yes, if you want to sign with a PDA then only a program can send the transaction. But this account struct allows for any type of signer.

Comment: The assumption here is op ix will get called by another program ix so as to sign via the pda and pass that sign on to the system program create account ix ser ?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. The PDA's signature will be passed to this program and then onto the system program instruction to create the account.

Comment: What if this not being called from another program? Can it be done?

Comment: Can you be more clear? Only programs can provide the signature for a PDA. So the point is moot